# NGINX limit_except breaks proxy_pass/rewrite functionality returning 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to establish authentification only for PUT and POST requests

```
        location /x/ {
            limit_except GET OPTIONS { 
                auth_basic "Write Access"; 
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/htpasswd_write; 
            } 
            rewrite ^ $request_uri;
            rewrite ^/x/(.*) $1 break;
            return 400; 
            proxy_pass http://server:8081/$uri;
        }
```

The whole rule set works fine without "limit_except" block. When turning the "limit_except" block on, i am requested for authentification, and then i am getting a 404 not found message from the proxied server (I see a tomcat error message).

I think something is wrong with the reqrute rule and the "$url" token. Does someone have an idea?

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1383 i found a bug report here, but need help to create the "mapping" rule